# Can the local streamable be subscribed?

Tags: dolphindb

Can the local streamable be subscribed?

code as below

```py
subscribeTable(tableName=`gpytest,actionName="judge",offset=0,handler=judge,msgAsTable=Ture)
```

error message

```py
Can't complete subscription because subscription is not enabled
```

why

Answer (score 0):

You should enable the subscription feature for the streaming data. Add the configuration items in the dolphindb.cfg file under single mode or add them in the cluster.cfg file under cluster mode. The specific configuration items are as follows:

- subPort: The port number that the subscription thread is listening on. This parameter must be specified to enable the node(s) to serve as subscriber(s).
- subExecutors: The number of message processing threads in the subscriber node. Only when subscription is enabled is this parameter relevant. If it is set to 0, it means the thread can conduct message parsing and can also process messages.
- maxSubConnections: The maximum number of publishers that the subscriber node can connect to. The default value is 64.
- subExecutorPooling: A Boolean value indicating whether streaming executors use pooling mode. The default value is false.
- maxSubQueueDepth: The maximum depth (number of records) of a message queue on the subscriber node.

You can refer to the streaming data tutorial:
https://github.com/dolphindb/Tutorials_eN/blob/master/streaming_tutorial.md